# Zoom content and use browser's scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, scrollbar

I've written following function to css-zoom my content which is working well:

```
function zoomContent(currentZoom) {
    $('#myContent').css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + currentZoom + ')',
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + currentZoom + ')',
        '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + currentZoom + ')',
        '-o-transform': 'scale(' + currentZoom + ')',
        '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + currentZoom + ')',
        '-moz-transform-origin': '50% 0%',
        '-o-transform-origin': '50% 0%',
        '-webkit-transform-origin': '50% 0%',
        '-ms-transform-origin': '50% 0%',
    });
```

and the div is placed inside of the main:

```
<div role='main' class='ui-content'>
   <div id='myContent'></div>
</div>
```

My question is how can I tell the browsers main scrollbars to reflect the zoomed content?

I've tried to set `html,body { overflow: auto; }` but the scrollbars didn't change. Setting the `.ui-content { overflow: auto; }` adds another scrollbar, but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: I tried using a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98yx4kka/1/) to repro your issue, but it seems like the scrollbars are working correctly by default? Maybe I'm missing your point?

Comment: It's hard to show in the fiddle. My web app takes the full browser window and it's height is bigger than the page so vertical scroll is shown by default. But then I zoom the content using JS, the main browsers scrollbar remains same. I expect it to become smaller.

Comment: I would expect that as well. Do you have any other css associated with the `myContent` element?